# Error when calling UseSwagger in Azure Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui

I have VS2015 and .Net Core Web API project created.
I'm following example in http://www.technicalblogs.sentientmindz.com/2017/04/09/enabling-swagger-support-to-the-web-api/

I have installed Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and next trying to code, but getting errors when using UseSwagger. Please advise me.

```
/* Startup.cs */
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using Microsoft.Owin;  
using Owin;  
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;  
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;  

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TestApi.Startup))]

namespace TestApi
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        /*use swagger added by me*/
        app.UseSwagger();      /*ERROR:iAppBuilder does not contain definition for UseSwagger…*/
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>. /*ERROR :iAppBuilder does not contain definition for UseSwaggerUI…*/
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Accounts API V1");  
        });  

    }

    //Add framework services by me
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "AcccountsAPI", Version = "v1" });  
        });  

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your code that you're using .Net Core v1.1, this is how I've done it:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        config.EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "WebAPI");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
            c.ResolveConflictingActions(x => x.First());

        }).EnableSwaggerUi();
    }

    protected static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return System.String.Format($@"{0}\bin\MyApi.XML",
                System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    }
```